# is_page() to display different wordpress post content using a template file

Tags: php, html, wordpress, templates, customization

I am trying to use *is_page()* to display to display 2 different contents in a single template file.. my code for this looks like

```
<?php

    if ( is_page('news') ) {

        // Insert HTML/PHP for News - code shown below
    }
    else ( is_page('review') ){

         // Insert HTML/PHP for Review - code shown below
    }
?>
```

This is not working for me... not sure why? I've shown the news/review code I try to insert below

HTML/PHP for News

```
<div class="news">
  <?php query_posts('cat=-89');?>
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <article class="summary">
    <div class="content_wrap cont_page ">
      <header>
        <h2> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?> </a></h2>
        <p> <span class="author">
          <?php the_author() ?>
          </span><br />
          <span class="date">
          <?php the_date(); ?>
          </span> 
      </header>
      <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
               <?php include('share.php')?> 
      </div>
      <aside class="right">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
      </aside>
    </div>
  </article>
  <?php
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

HTML/PHP for Review

```
<div class="review">
  <?php query_posts('cat=89,246,247,248');?>
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <article class="summary 
  <?php

  // Custom posts stylings
if ( has_post_format( 'video' )) {
    echo 'video';
} elseif ( in_category('orange') ) {
    echo 'orange';
} else {
    echo 'white';}
?>


  ">
    <div class="content_wrap cont_page ">
      <div class="entry-content">
        <?php  if ( has_post_format( 'video' )) {
    // Get the video URL and put it in the $video variable
                        $videoID = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_url', true);
                        // Echo the embed code via oEmbed
                        echo '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'.$videoID.'?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff" width="405" height="285" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>'; 
                    //  echo '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'.$videoID.'" width="405" height="285" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>';
            }
                else the_post_thumbnail();

 ?>
      </div>
      <aside class="right">
        <header>
          <h2> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?> </a></h2>
        </header>
        <div class="entry-content">
          <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div>
        <?php include('share.php')?>
      </aside>
    </div>
  </article>
  <?php

// DISABLED/S default format

// get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: is_page() is case sensitive I believe. So page titles need to match exactly.  Try using the page id instead.

Comment: that part is fine it's the syntax for somereason cant use <?php --- ?> within if statement :-/

Answer (score 0):

Use page ID as the parameter for your is_page() to be more accurate. You might edit the page name at some point and then your code will fail.

```
if(is_page(10)) { 
    // do something
  } else if (is_page(20)) {
    // do something
  } else { 
    // do something else
}
```

I'm pretty sure this was a typo, but the line below should an be **else if**:

```
else ( is_page('review') ){
```

Also, after  in both the templates, you have extra open php braces.

Comment: the syntax for somereason cant use <?php --- ?> within if statement ?

Comment: As long as you open and close the php braces properly, you can use the anywhere. Can you paste your code to show where it is not working?